# Yii2 validation in separate actions for render and post form

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have tried different approach for create action.

Usually i have one action which renders, validates and saves data.

Now i want two separate actions. One for rendering view and second for validation and data storage.

**View**

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['ew/eshop-create'],
    'method' => 'post',
]);

echo $form->field($model, 'input')->textarea([
    'rows' => '20'
]);

echo Html::submitButton(
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> Odoslať',
    [
        'class' => 'btn btn-success',
        'name' => 'create-button'
    ]
);

ActiveForm::end();
```

**Model**

```
class EshopCreate extends Model
{
    public $input;

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'input' => 'JSON vstup'
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['input', 'required'],
            ['input', 'validateInput'],
        ];
    }

    public function validateInput()
    {
        // validate json
        $this->addError('input', 'Something is wrong');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class EwController extends Controller
{
    public function actionEshopCreateForm()
    {
        $model = new EshopCreate();

        return $this->render('eshop-create-form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }

    public function actionEshopCreate()
    {
        $model = new EshopCreate();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            exit('create');
        }

        return $this->redirect(['ew/eshop-create-form']);
     }
}
```

**Edit:**
So i had problem with validation. I switched `model->load` and `model->validate` in `actionEshopCreate`.

So it works fine, but message from `validateInput` is not displayed. Also when i turn off clientvalidation, there are no error messages at all. So my question is how to pass errors from one action to another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to a different action when the form is submitted and fail to pass the validation

```
return $this->redirect(['ew/eshop-create-form']);
```

the EshopCreate model will lose all validation messages when the redirection happens

Probably you want to do something like this

```
class EwController extends Controller
{
    public function actionEshopCreateForm()
    {
        $model = new EshopCreate();

        return $this->render('eshop-create-form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }

    public function actionEshopCreate()
    {
        $model = new EshopCreate();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) 
        {
             //store the model data in session or somewhere for example where you can retrieve it later in the actionEshopCreateForm() action
             return $this->redirect(['ew/eshop-create-form']);
        }

        return $this->render('eshop-create-form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
     }
}
```